# Solving the Navier-Stokes equations for a known density function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

Consider the following form for the Navier-Stokes equations for a compressible fluid in steady-state:

$$div(\rho \textbf v)=0$$
$$div(\rho \textbf{vv} )=-k^2 \nabla \rho$$

where k is a constant. If the density is a known function of 3D space, is it possible to solve for the velocity function $\bf{v}$?
The type of density functions I'm interested in would be of the form:
$$\rho=\frac{c}{(R^2 + x^2 +y^2+z^2)^{n/2}}$$
where n is an integer.

Comment: $div(\rho v) = 0$ is a homogeneous linear partial differential equation in $v$, $div(\rho v^2) = -k^2 \nabla \rho$ is a non-homogeneous linear partial differential equation in $v^2$.

Comment: Isn't this system overdetermined? 4 equations, 3 unknowns? Also, this is inviscid fluid, right?

Comment: Maybe [this will help.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier–Stokes_equations#A_three-dimensional_steady-state_vortex_solution)

Comment: @David yes it's overdetermined if you take the density function I used, but I'm just trying to give an idea of the type of solutions I'd like, rather than specifying it has to be as I wrote. I've seen the solution you linked to, unfortunately it doesn't satisfy the simple pressure term I used ($\nabla P=c^2 \nabla \rho$) - I think it requires the density to be a rather unphysical function.

Comment: If you put $n=2$ into your density, you get exactly the density profile in the linked solution!

Comment: @David Yes, but yhat solution corresponds to the equation of state $p \propto \rho^{3}$ whereas here $p \propto \rho$. One suggestion for OP is to try an ansatz on the same form $\vec{v} = \frac{\vec{u}}{(R^2+x^2+y^2+z^2)^m}$ where $\vec{u}$ is some polynomial in $x,y,z$ and try to see if one can tweek out a solution.

Comment: Note that the pressure in the link is also negative.